# cURL login hangs on curl_exec

Tags: post, curl, authentication

I'm trying to login to a website using cURL. My code works on other websites, but on this one it hangs on curl_exec, Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.

I know similar questions have been asked and I've look at them all...I've been trying every combination and modification for my script I can think of, with no luck. Any suggestions?

```
$username = 'myUsername';
$password = 'myPassword';

$url="https://www.centraldispatch.com/login/"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

if (! file_exists($cookie) || ! is_writable($cookie))
{
    echo 'Cookie file missing or not writable.';
    exit;
}


$postFields = array(
  'Username' => $username,
  'Password' => $password,
  'r' => '' //a hidden field in the form
);

$postdata = http_build_query($postFields);

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);   
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");  
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); //code hangs here

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: works for me with myUsername as is. But I think a cookie file may not exists for the very first run. Why do you check it?

Comment: I checked it to ensure that it wasn't a cookie causing the problem. So the code above worked for you without issue (without logging in of course)?

Comment: Yes, it does not hang for me. Try not use CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, use jar line only.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I uploaded my script to another server and it did work, so it must be an issue with my local wamp configuration...strange since I can log into facebook and other sites. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andrey for helping me figure out the problem was with my wamp configuration, not with the script.